# I want to validate a phone number using regexp in flutter with 11 digit and should always start with 09

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I am working with regexp in dart for my flutter project. the digit should be 11 digits and the first 2 digits should always start with 09 and the remaining 9 digits can be any numbers.

```
RegExp regExp = new RegExp(
      r"(0/91)?[7-9][0-9]{9}");
        
        if (regExp.hasMatch("09123979064")) {
            print("valid");
        } else {
            print("invalid phone number");
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `(0/91)?[7-9][0-9]{9}` regex matches an optional `0/91` substring capturing it into Group 1 and then matches `7`, `8` or `9` digit, and then nine more digits *anywhere* inside the string.

You need

```dart
RegExp regExp = new RegExp("^09[0-9]{9}$");
```

where

- `^` - start of string
- `09` - a `09` substring
- `[0-9]{9}` - nine digits
- `$` - end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://09123979064).